# SQL query for second largest value with a where condition

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with step id and resident id. I wanted to write a query find the second largest step id for a particular resident.

The query using max in the google examples doesn't have the where clause. 
Tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(step_action_id) 
FROM step_table where resident_id =219 
ORDER BY step_action_id DESC limit 2,1;
```

Table:

```
Step_Action_id REsident_id
800               218
801               218
911               218
857               218       
856               219
858               219
```

Result am expecting is 856. but i am getting the below error,

```
Error: ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD LIMIT.  TOKEN SKIP OPTIMIZE FOR FETCH , EXCEPT MINUS UNION <END-OF-STATEMENT> WAS EXPECTED. SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.59.81
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -199
Error: THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=3.59.81
SQLState:  26501
ErrorCode: -
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is ***not*** a function.

Comment: what platform and version of DB2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the step ids are distinct, you can just use `OFFSET` and `FIRST FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`:

```
SELECT step_action_id
FROM step_table 
WHERE resident_id = 219 
ORDER BY step_action_id DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

If they are not distinct, just add a `GROUP BY` or `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT step_action_id
FROM step_table 
WHERE resident_id = 219 
GROUP BY step_action_id
ORDER BY step_action_id DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: syntax is `OFFSET 1 ROWS` in db2 and it is specifically not recommended -> http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059212.html

Comment: @Hogan . . . I see nothing in that documentation to say it is not recommended.  Nor here:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061832.html.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear -- the limit syntax is what is not recommended -- which I thought was in your answer but maybe it was in another answer... In any case the limit keywork is the one they don't recommend.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT step_action_id
FROM (
  SELECT step_action_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY step_action_id DESC) AS rn
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT step_action_id
        FROM step_table 
        WHERE resident_id = 219
     ) AS s
) AS s2
WHERE rn = 2;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/FYWUTT30056)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

ROW_NUMBER() works just fine but you should also know DB2 uses "FETCH FIRST" not LIMIT to "restrict" the number of rows returned.  So you could get 2 with a subquery and then reverse the order to get the 2nd one.  Like this:

```
SELECT step_action_id 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT step_action_id 
  FROM step_table 
  WHERE resident_id =219 
  ORDER BY step_action_id DESC
  FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
)
ORDER BY step_action_id ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for letting me know various ways to resolve this. I got it resolved using the below query

SELECT max(step_action_id) FROM step_table as p WHERE p.step_action_id < (SELECT max(t.step_action_id) FROM step_table as t where t.residentId = 219) and p.residentId = 219";